# In the training of a neural network, the validation loss increase and then decrease with the trainning loss?

Tags: neural-networks, validation

When i train a MLP to learn a data map relationship, but i find behavior of the validation loss is very weird. The validation loss increase first and then it decrease with the trainning losss. But the training loss derease all the time.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried multiple training runs of your MLP using different initial weights? If so, is this happening every time, or just on one/some runs?

Comment: I trained the neural network with the different initial weights provided in pytorch. That happened most often, and at other times, the validation loss is lower than training loss at first ,and then they converged into almost the same together with each other. Now, i guess that it is because of the high similarity between training and validation datasets, which will lead to the almost same loss value. With respect to the lower validation loss, i think it is due to the application of batch normalization.